# Does OpenWrt offer packet filter api?

Tags: c++, openwrt

I wonder if there existing an api for me to create a package.I want to capture packets and filter them on the router,but i didn't find the api for my purpose.Can anyone tell me does OpenWrt has the C++ api like what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use libpcap to capture and filter packets.
Here is the man page for [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html)